# How to show admobs interstitial ads more than once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, admob, interstitial

Anyone know how to show interstitial admobs more than once? I wrote it in swift, but I have objective C below.

I have a func to preload the ad

```
func preLoadInterstitial () {

    intertitialRequest.testDevices = [GAD_SIMULATOR_ID]
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.loadRequest(intertitialRequest)  
}
```

Then a function to call the ad

```
 func showInterstitial() {
    println("interstitial")
    interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}
```

Lastly a function to try to re-request an interstitial ad after you close the ad.

```
func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

    self.preLoadInterstitial()
}
```

However, after I close the ad, I get the error "Request Error: Will not send request because interstitial object has been used." Then the program won't load any more interstitials. So how do you request/show another interstitial ad?

I think the equivalent of my code in objective C would look like this

```
(void)showInterstital {

    self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self;
}

(void)preLoadInterstitial {
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request]
}

(void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    self.interstitial = [self preLoadInterstitial];
}
```

Any help in swift or objective-C would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to call interstitial.loadRequest(intertitialRequest) (with a new request object) prior to showing each interstitial.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I have been reading everywhere. I guess I can't request the same interstitial object twice. Thanks!